# Printing a report make Apache unresponsive

Tags: java, apache, web-applications, jasper-reports

The problem Occurs when I print the report via *jsp*.

Firstly I thought its more like a memory error i.e. permgen space of *NetBeans* but it shouldn't occur when you deploy the application and it becomes live but the problem is still there.

The report printing works fine for like first 6-7 reports and then the application becomes unresponsive and to make it work again I have to stop the *Apache* and run the application again

Here is the code that I have used to print the reports via *jsp*

```
try {
    JasperReport jasperReport;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    JasperDesign jasperdesign;
    String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports/admissionReport.jrxml");
    String imagepath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images//");
    String imageSubPath = File.separatorChar + "";
    imagepath = imagepath + imageSubPath;
    jasperdesign = JRXmlLoader.load(path);
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperdesign);
    Connection con = this.getServiceFactory().getReportService().getDao().getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
    paramMap.put("imagePath", imagepath);
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, paramMap, con);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports/admissionReport.pdf"));
    String filename = getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports/admissionReport.pdf");
    File rtf = new File(filename);
    int readBytes = 0;
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=30");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"admissionReport\"");
    response.setContentLength((int) rtf.length());
    input = new FileInputStream(rtf);
    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(input);
    OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
    while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1) {
        stream.write(readBytes);
    }
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
} catch (Exception exp) {
    throw new Exception("Error occured while saving record.." + exp.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

So far I cannot find the solution over the internet.

P.S I am using *Spring* framework for the development.

I would like to know if anyone have a solution to this problem.

Comment: `/images//` has one slash too much at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buf.close()` is missing; `input.close()` not needed then. At the moment a bit unsure whether `stream.close()` not is contra-indicated - but it works. You could try `con.close()`.

Tip:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(rtf.length()));

Files.copy(rtf.toPath(), stream);
```

The last is a Java 7 utility to copy a file to a stream, replacing the byte wise reading, which even with BufferedInputStream is not optimal.

Comment: ok the copy thing ive replaced to make it more optimal. the reason for the server to become unresponsive was too many connection so the con.close() worked for me thankx